# Calling a function in UIView class? With Obj C on Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to call a function called animateRight in a file called ScanAnimation.m from SecondViewController.m.

In the top of SecondViewController.m I have:

```
ScanAnimation * Animation = [[ScanAnimation alloc] init];
```

and I make the call with:

```
[Animation animateRight];
```

and I get the error:

'ScanAnimation' undeclared

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the ScanAnimation header file into the file you are making the call in.

So in the SecondViewController.m you would add `#import "ScanAnimation.h"` at the top under `#import "SecondViewController.h"`

Comment: Ok, you need to declare it in the header file for the ScanAnimation class. What you do is copy the -(void)animateRight part and put it in the header file like this. -(void)animateRight;